# Is Redux needed for every ReactJS project?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a question: Is Redux needed for every ReactJS project for development?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Absolutely not

Long answer:
You seem to be new here, so here are a few points that might help you

1. As your application grows in size and complexity managing the state will become harder, that is why tools like redux where created, they provide a certain abstraction that allows you not only to reason about your code in a more simple way but also to separate state management logic from other code, therefore redux will HELP you in this regard.
2. There are many tools to do state management, redux is one of them, but there is also mobx, mobx-state-tree, useReducer, using contexts, etc etc. they all have pros and cons, however in the end the point is the same to HELP you manage the state of your application.
3. You should try it yourself, try to develop a complex workflow without any state management tool first, see how it feels, then you might understand why having tooling that supports you is very useful, but not absolutely necessary.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't required, you can check official react tutorial not using any redux.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's totally up to you on how you want to handle the state of your React app.

You can go with the Context API that react ships with if you don't want to add any third party library.

Further I'd suggest you give the following article a read, it's by Dan Abramov, he is the co-author of Redux and Create React App.

**You might not need redux**
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Answer (score 0):

No you don't, There are many state management frameworks except redux

1)  Mobx - https://mobx.js.org/README.html

2) ReactN - https://mernapps.com/simple-reactjs-global-state-management-with-reactn/

These are way easier to implement compared to redux and there is no connection between react and these state management frameworks.

You can use pure react to manage states -https://blog.logrocket.com/state-management-using-only-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

No, Redux is not necessary for every ReactJS project. It is useful for managing complex state and data flow, but for smaller projects with simpler state management needs, it may be unnecessary and add unnecessary overhead.

In React 18, the [context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) allows you to pass data down the component tree without the need for props drilling. It is useful for managing global state or data that is shared across multiple components.

However, if you still want to use a state management lib, you many refer to [Top React State Management Libraries Ranking](https://fe-tool.com/awesome-react-state-management)

Personally, I prefer to use [zustand](https://npm-compare.com/zustand) for managing state. This library is built on React's Context API and emphasizes the use of hooks as the main method of accessing state. There's no requirement to encase your application in context providers. Very easy to use!

Read more: [Comparison of react state management libs](https://npm-compare.com/@reduxjs/toolkit,zustand,xstate,mobx,recoil,jotai/#timeRange=THREE_YEARS)